# What's the difference between "bloke", "chap" and "lad"?

Tags: differences, nouns, british-english

Several synonyms are used in the UK: *bloke, chap, lad*. What's the difference between them?

Comment: Not enough data. Cannot compute. Please supply the results of your research with dictionary and thesaurus (so others don't repeat that) and provide some context. Some words have different connotations depending on where they are used.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I saw the word 'bloke' in the computer game, referring to the Nazies: 'those bloody blokes'. I know, that the word 'lad' is quite often used by the Scots. And just wanted to understand, in what contexts could these synonyms be used and to what extent they are interchangeable.

Comment: This question is incomplete. Please edit to include your research results and sources you have consulted. Voting to close "not a real question" in the meantime.

Comment: @MετάEd Added the data.

Comment: What do you mean by “my British fellow”?  Presumably someone over here on an academic fellowship, I should hope.

Comment: @user4035 At this point, since you seem now to have answered your own question in the question, you might want to post an answer.

Comment: @MετάEd ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster says:

1. *bloke* — "(British, informal) man, fellow"
2. *chap* — "(British) fellow. Origin of chap: chapman"
3. *lad* — "a male person of any age between early boyhood and maturity"

So, it seems, that *lad* can be related only to a young person. While *chap* and *bloke* to any male person.

My British fellow said:

> *Chap* is more delicate; *bloke* is rougher a bit. *Chap* is posh, *bloke* is common.